# Apache Ignite - not loading fromCache method

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

Trying out apache ignite to use spark RDD's/DF's across multiple sessions.

Followed the instructions as in `"https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/testing-integration-with-spark-shell"`.

Hitting the error below on loading fromCache method.

```
scala> val sharedRDD = ic.fromCache[Integer, Integer]("partitioned")
<console>:35: error: overloaded method value fromCache with alternatives:
  (cacheCfg: org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration[Nothing,Nothing])org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD[Nothing,Nothing] <and>
  (cacheName: String)org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD[Nothing,Nothing]
 does not take type parameters
         val sharedRDD = ic.fromCache[Integer, Integer]("partitioned")
```

Not sure what am i missing here. Any suggestions will be of help. Thanks

Comment: Does `val sharedRDD = ic.fromCache[Integer, Integer](new CacheConfiguration[Integer, Integer]("partitioned"))` work?

Comment: Try specifying the type as follows:

`val sharedRDD:org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD[Integer,Integer] = ic.fromCache("partitioned")`

instead of passing it as parameter to the ic.fromCache function.